# Box which whould be vertically thin with not enough content, but would have scrollbar when there is too much content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In a project I'm cooperating on (using Bootstrap 4) I would like to create a box which would have a scroll-bar when there is too much content, like here:

[image]

but when there is only few bullets in it, it would shrink to appropriate height, not like what we have now (simply I want to get rid of that vertical unused witespace):

[image]

HTML I'm using now is:

```
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h2>Domains (258)</h2>
      <ul class="overflow-auto domain-list">
        <li><a href="...">1bh3A00</a></li>
        [...]
        <li><a href="...">8prnA00</a></li>
      </ul>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <a href="....csv"><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Domains CSV</button></a>
```

CSS for that is only:

```
.domain-list { height: 30em; }
```

I assume I'm missing something obvious, but was not able to google anything helpful. Any idea please?

Comment: I am no CSS guru, but I think you can set `max-height` instead of height and set scroll to auto.

Comment: Hello @NoNameProvided! Looks like I'm not getting scrollbar with `.domain-list { max-height: 2em; overflow: auto; }` or `overflow: scroll` :-/

Comment: It should work, I have added an example as the answer.

Comment: @NoNameProvided is correct even if their example is a bit abstracted from yours and doesn't include bootstrap.css. All you need to do in your example is change the ` height: 30em;` to `max-height: 30em;` See here: https://jsfiddle.net/1r74203d/

Comment: Found an issue here. Mine problem was `overflow-auto` in `<ul class="overflow-auto domain-list">`. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via applying `max-height` on your container instead of specifying height. This will make the container take as much hight as needed but not more than the specified maximum. Below you can find a simple example, after adding the 7th row the container should become scrollable as there is more content in it than the allowed `max-height`.

```js
let rowNumber = 2;

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const newRow = document.createElement('div');
  newRow.classList.add('row');
  newRow.innerText = `Row #${rowNumber++}`;

  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(newRow);
});
```

```css
.list {
  max-height: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.row {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px; /* this is not needed, just makes the example text aligned */
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.row:nth-child(even) {
  background: rgb(15, 156, 250);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="list" class="list">
    <div class="row">Row #1</div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <button id="add">Add row</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you - mine problem was `overflow-auto` in `<ul class="overflow-auto domain-list">`. When removed, works like a charm!